# *example* of a Amazon MWS POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ Flat File and Validator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am trying to upload a flat file of product data to MWS. I want to use a tab delimited, flat file.

Could someone please provide an example of a correctly formatted flat file that I could copy and paste into the MWS Scratchpad?

Also is there some type of validator at amazon where I could test my flat file and verify that it's correctly formatted before I send it along?

Comment: Check out the mws help system. There are templates there.

Comment: This question is not too broad. :) I asked for a specific example and Beebs, to his credit, offered one. Hence the vote up and the vote as best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not one already, you would need to sign up as a Professional seller in order to access the Inventory File Templates which will validate your data. I assume you are trying to create new products that don't already exist on Amazon or add/change data on existing products. For this you would need one of the Category Specific Inventory Files. 
https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200186090

Let's say you're trying to upload a flat file for Books. You would first download the Flat.File.BookLoader template from the above URL. Fill out your data. Fill out your MWS security credentials on the Add-Ins tab. Click the Validate button on the Add-Ins tab. If everything is good, click Upload File, also on the Add-Ins tab.

There's also the Check File feature at the Seller Central website > Inventory > Add Products via Upload > Upload Inventory Files > "Select type of file to upload" > Check File button.

I just saved 1 line of test data from within the template as a tab delimited text file. There's 3 rows of Amazon headers and a LOT of columns. Some columns require data in order to be valid, others do not. Here's what I got:

```
TemplateType=BookLoader Version=2013.1024   The top 3 rows are for Amazon.com use only. Do not modify or delete the top 3 rows.                                 Offer - These attributes are required to make your item buyable for customers on the site                                   Discovery - These attributes have an effect on how customers can find your product on the site using browse or search                   Image - These attributes provide links to images for a product                      Fulfillment - Use these columns to provide fulfillment-related information for either Amazon-fulfilled (FBA) or seller-fulfilled orders.                            Ungrouped - These attributes create rich product listings for your buyers.                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
SKU Product ID  Product ID Type Title   Publisher   Product Description Update Delete   Author  Binding Publication date    Edition Number  Standard Price  Quantity    Item Condition  Offer Condition Note    Product Tax Code    Expedited Shipping  Will Ship Internationally   Standard Plus   Scheduled Delivery SKU List Search Terms1   Search Terms2   Search Terms3   Search Terms4   Search Terms5   Main Image URL  Main Offer Image    Offer Image1    Offer Image2    Offer Image3    Offer Image4    Fulfillment Center ID   Package Height  Package Width   Package Length  Package Dimensions Unit Of Measure  Package Weight  Package Weight Unit Of Measure  Subject Language    Illustrator Signed By   Dust Jacket Condition   Pages   Number in Series    Series Title    Editor  Preface Colorist    Compiler    Composer1   Composer2   Composer3   Composer4   Composer5   Composer6   Composer7   Composer8   Composer9   Composer10  Creator Drawings    Painter Reader  Series Editor   Technical editor    Adapter Afterword   Artist1 Artist2 Artist3 Artist4 Artist5 Artist6 Artist7 Artist8 Artist9 Artist10    Foreword    Introduction    Translator  Photographer    Digital Media Format1   Digital Media Format2   Digital Media Format3   Digital Media Format4   Digital Media Format5   Digital Media Format6   Digital Media Format7   Digital Media Format8   Digital Media Format9   Digital Media Format10
item_sku    external_product_id external_product_id_type    item_name   manufacturer    product_description update_delete   author  binding publication_date    edition standard_price  quantity    condition_type  condition_note  product_tax_code    expedited_shipping  will_ship_internationally   standard_plus   delivery_schedule_group_id  generic_keywords1   generic_keywords2   generic_keywords3   generic_keywords4   generic_keywords5   main_image_url  main_offer_image    offer_image1    offer_image2    offer_image3    offer_image4    fulfillment_center_id   package_height  package_width   package_length  package_dimensions_unit_of_measure  package_weight  package_weight_unit_of_measure  unknown_subject language_value  illustrator signed_by   dust_jacket_description pages   series_number   collection_name editor  preface colorist    compiler    composer1   composer2   composer3   composer4   composer5   composer6   composer7   composer8   composer9   composer10  creator drawings    painter reader  series_editor   technical_editor    adapter afterword   artist1 artist2 artist3 artist4 artist5 artist6 artist7 artist8 artist9 artist10    foreword    introduction    translator  photographer    format1 format2 format3 format4 format5 format6 format7 format8 format9 format10
10162513    0452011876  UPC Olympus Camedia C-50 Digital Camera Sony            J.K.Rowling paperback   1994                                                                http://www.companyname.com/images/1250.main.jpg
```